# I want to add a datepicker in ionic framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I am a beginner in ionic and angular j s. 
I want to insert a date picker in ionic and to get value from that.
Anybody have some choices to solve this

Comment: i treid bootstrap datepicker but it doesnt work

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ionic Framework has no Datepicker yet. But you can still invoke a "native" Datepicker by using a simple input tag like this:

```
<input type="date">
```

or trying one of thoses:

- https://github.com/joshilomas/DatePicker-IonicApp
- https://github.com/mrfoh/cordova-datepicker-plugin
- https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/332
- https://github.com/alongubkin/angular-datepicker

Comment: Simply go with the <input type="date">    and it will do the job.  I wasted pretty much the whole day trying to make other add ons work.  Some work but at the cost of other capabilities.  Unless you are looking for fancy popup or modal calendars this will do the job.   Don't even need the Cordova Date Picker plugin unless you need to specify time.

Answer (score 14):

I have create a ionic-datepicker bower component. You can use it. No additional dependencies are required. And it wont use the native components. Its purely ionic frameworks component. https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-datepicker

You can even have a look at the ionic-timepicker bower component. No additional dependencies are required. https://github.com/rajeshwarpatlolla/ionic-timepicker

Comment: @Rajeshwar: Thank you so much for this plugin, i tried another one but that was so slow, then i came to this page. Your plugin is quite fast and provides lot of options. thanks !

Comment: Thanks for your nice control, appreciate for your contribution. However, when I include both date picker and time picker under same page, no matter which button I clicked, it still shows the calendar popup.

Comment: There should be two different objects for two components. May be you are using same set of code snippet for both of them. Could you please share your code snippet?

Comment: @Rajeshwar Great work, however I am working where clients select from a limited selection of available dates with hours and I cannot seen to get `disabledDates` to be `!disabledDates` where they can only select for the available dates. Does this support what would be "`abledDates`" where they can only select from a select few?

Comment: As of now, there is no such feature. You can disable particular dates, disable from and to, but you can't enable only a few dates.